# How do I convert an encrypted string into a SecureString

Tags: c#, powershell, encryption, securestring

I have not seen this exact question asked and answered, although there is a lot of Q/A about `SecureString`.

I have a password that I converted to an encrypted string using PowerShell:

```
"password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File ".\securepass.txt"
```

Now I want to take that encrypted string, stick it in my C# application and then convert it to a `SecureString` and use it with:

```
Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, SecureString);
```

I'm not worried that it can't be hacked - it's just to hide the password from someone casually looking at the code.

Or is there another / easier encryption technique for this case?

So the question is, how do I convert from encrypted to `SecureString` in C#?

Comment: When a user encrypts a password they are the only one who can decrypt it. You need to use a form of encryption/encoding that is two-way and doesn't use a personal-key so it can by use by multiple people.

Comment: You would be better looking at obfuscation, something like this: [Simple obfuscation of string in .NET?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13025949)

Comment: The user/machine limitation can be worked around with the "key" parameter to the securestring cmdlets.
There is a good writeup here: https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/

Comment: Yes, I've used a key, which makes the secure string portable: "ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key". But what I'm asking is specifically how to convert an encrypted string into a SecureString. Thanks!